# Foreach object loop

Tags: c#, loops, object, foreach

My already code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in items)
{
    if (keyValuePair.Key == "animals")
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> animal = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        animal.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        object animalObject = keyValuePair.Value;
        foreach (??? in animalObject)
        {

        }
    }
    object fajny = keyValuePair.Value;

    result2 = fajny as ArrayCollection;
}
```

I want to loop Dictionary elements from animalObject object:

> http://scr.hu/0tgp/6dteu
>   http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/1h/1p/05/3p9fyc.jpg

I don't have an idea how do this. I cant search help anywhere.

Comment: What _is_ the `object`?

Comment: with a var or other object it should let you do it but your code looks weird, you have nothing defined

Comment: What is the underlying type of object for your animalObject?  I'm assuming it is some sort of collection as you're trying to iterate on it.

Comment: if your `Value` in `items` has some meaning beside plain `object`, you ought to have `Dictionary<string, SomeCollection>` instead.

Comment: There's possibly a method like .Iterator you can call on animalObject and iterate over that. But why would an 'animal' be defined by a set of strings and other objects?

Comment: animal: http://scr.hu/0tgp/i8e4g

Comment: animalObject http://scr.hu/0tgp/6dteu

Comment: Im not sure why you are looping the dictionary to find "animals". You should be able to do:
`foreach (var animal in items["animals"])
{
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cast to `IEnumerable`, but I would suggest trying to retain strong typing.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in items)
{
    if (keyValuePair.Key == "animals")
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> animal = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        animal.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        IEnumerable animalObject = keyValuePair.Value as IEnumerable;

        if(animalEnumerable != null)
        {
            foreach (object animalObj in animalEnumerable)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to loop over the values in your dictionary: `animal`?

```
    foreach (object animalObject in animal.Values)
    {

    }
```

Comment: http://scr.hu/0tgp/42s5d
I want to loop objects (Dictionary<string,object>) from first to final